# List of Tuples as a function Parameter in Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, parameters, tuples

How do define a function with a parameter that is a list of tuples? So an example of the input would be

```
[("hey", False), ("you", True)]
```

My function takes the list of tuples as: [(String, Bool)]
So here is what it looks like:

```
aFunc :: [(String, Bool)] -> Bool
aFunc ???? =
```

So what do I fill in for the ???? to be able to access my tuple? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Edit:

```
aFunc :: [(String, Bool)] -> Bool
aFunc aTuple = mapM_ lookup aTuple?
```

So how do I access my tuple in a function? That doesn't work.

Comment: The question is too vague. What function are you trying to implement?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how I can access my tuple. So normally I would do something like; 
aFunc :: String -> Bool -> Bool
aFunc stringInput aBool = case aBool of... 

I'm asking what I would place in the ???? instead of stringInput or aBool for accessing an item in the tuple list.

Comment: There's nothing special about a list of tuples - you'll have to treat the argument as a list, whose items are, well, tuples :) I'd need some more info for a more specific answer.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a function which takes a string (i.e. `"Hey"`) and return a matching boolean value from the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to implement your own version of [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup). You can write a simple version using list comprehension:

```
lookup' :: String -> [(String,Bool)] -> Bool
lookup' k lkp = head $ [v | (k',v) <- lkp, k'==k]
```

Or using `filter`:

```
lookup'' :: String -> [(String,Bool)] -> Bool
lookup'' k lkp = snd $ head $ filter ((==k) . fst) lkp
```

Notice that these versions are unsafe - that is, they'll fail with an ugly and uninformative error if the list doesn't contain your item:

```
ghci> lookup' "foo" [("bar",True)]
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

You can solve this issue by writing your own custom error message:

```
lookupErr :: String -> [(String,Bool)] -> Bool
lookupErr k lkp = case [v | (k',v) <- lkp, k'==k] of
                     (v:_) -> v
                     [] -> error "Key not found!"
```

A better approach is to return a `Maybe Bool` instead:

```
lookupMaybe :: String -> [(String,Bool)] -> Maybe Bool
lookupMaybe k lkp = case [v | (k',v) <- lkp, k'==k] of
                     (v:_) -> Just v
                     [] -> Nothing
```

The library version takes this approach, and has a more generic signature:

```
lookup :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
```

You can read its implementation [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-List.html#lookup).

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for but I was trying to get there myself. Thanks. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help, and sorry if my answer was too specific. Reading through the [`Data.List` source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-List.html) is a great way to learn Haskell basics. It contains a lot of simple function implemented in an elegant way and is a great source for good Haskell habits :)